# Twig : Display formated text in Textarea

Tags: symfony, twig

I am storing the formatted text in the table which contains html tags (`<br />, <strong>`, etc).
If I use raw attribute in the div, it show perfectly but not in textarea. How I can display the formatted content in the textarea?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a [Rich Text Editor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_rich-text_editor). The standard HTML textarea tag only accepts plain text (even if the text is or includes HTML markup).

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Ivory CKEditor](https://github.com/egeloen/IvoryCKEditorBundle). You can simply require it to symfony2 project using composer:

```
composer require egeloen/ckeditor-bundle
```

[image]